# Why different admob publisher id for android & iphone

Tags: admob

I created admob publisher id for android app

But when I inserted this id into my iphone app still the ads were appearing.

So if a single publisher id is working on both android & iphone then why should i create 2 different publisher id for SAME APP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using different id, admob can send appropriate ads to each device. 
Ex: if the ad is about a new iPhone App, you dont want to see it in your android device.

Please somebody can correct if i am wrong....

Comment: Making sure you get app download ads for the right platform is one reason (although AdMob may have other ways of determining platform as well).  To supplement this answer, you also get finer grained reporting if you create two publisher ids.  You'll have a better idea on how each app is performing.

Comment: even i had similar reasoning but wasnt sure about it....anyways Ar1f ur example was dot on the mark...thanks